# Update using a select in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

How can I produce an update using a select on the same table (in the same SQL)?

I would like to select the last inserted row and update it with new values.

Comment: Use http://es.stackoverflow.com/ instead for questions in Spanish.

Comment: It's a poor question irrespective of the language.

Comment: If you have a `WHERE` clause, that let's you select the right rows for retrieval, you can also use it to select the right rows for an `UPDATE`. Then there is no need for a `SELECT`. You can address the old values of a row in an `UPDATE` too. If a column appears in the expression in a `column = expression` in the `SET` clause, it evaluate to its old value.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL there's no such thing as "the last inserted row". If you need it, you need to mark it somehow.

Per SQL standard, the database can return the rows of a table in any order. If you need a specific order you need to specify it using `order by`. Behind the scenes databases reorganize the data as they see fit to improve performance, backing up, clustering, etc. The rows are by no means stored in the order you inserted them.

In simple words, SQL databases are not Excel sheets.

Having said that, if you still need to update the last "inserted" row, you could:

- Add an extra column with a timestamp. Then you can search the "max" timestamp value and find it.
- Add an extra column with a sequence number, or identity column. Same idea as before but using an integer.
- Add a boolean flag column that identifies the last row. You would need to "move the flag" on each insert, though.
- Store the "id" of the last inserted row in a separate table. You would need to update this id on every insert.

Off the top of my head those are the solutions I can see.